# Хорошие учебники "для совсем ламеров" по PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день, дорогой ХэшКод, пишет тебе начинающий быдлокодер!

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, хороших учебников "для совсем ламеров" по PHP, на великом и могучем Русском языке, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: <?php
    echo "hello world!";
    ?>

Это косточка программирования всех языков :D

Comment: > пишет тебе начинающий быдлокодер

+1

А по существу, полностью поддерживаю @exec! Книги пустое место, и аналогично не читал ниодной!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужны никакие учебники**.** Я не читал ни одного учебника, даже в первом классе**.**

Сначала учите синтаксис**,** потом ставьте простую задачу и решайте её**.** Когда начнете понимать что к чему - почитайте о ООП**,** сделайте пробный сайт**.**

Когда сайт будет готов - пишите сюда и давайте ссылку на сайт, оценим с достоинством**.** =)

Comment: Вот вот... достаточно иметь под рукой справочник функций и логику в голове...

Comment: > справочник функций

Он справа от адресной строки. =)

Comment: Смотря какой браузер)))) Ну я согласен... Но всеже я скачал php.su-ный справочник, для быстрого реагирования.

Comment: > Я не читал ни одного учебника, даже в первом классе.

> почитайте о ООП

@exec, советую вам учебники все-таки почитать. Хотя бы по русскому языку.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, да, тут вы правы.

Answer (score 3):

- php.net
- php.ru
- php.su (здесь вроде туториалы есть)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал почитать:

> "Самоучитель PHP 5 / 6 (3 издание)"
> (издательство БХВ-Петербург, 2009 г.).
> Авторы: Кузнецов М.В, Симдянов И.В.".

Минус книги - не описана работа с сокетами, но на начальном этапе это не актуально, да и нет ничего идеального.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью Не согласен с вами.Книги нужно читать,но при одном условии,надо знать основы.Так как не имея собственного опыта,мы полагаемся на опыт автора книги.

Answer (score -1):

PHP само по себе для ламеров.

следовательно из определения и условий задачи, "хорошие учебники по PHP для совсем ламеров" является пустым множеством.

таким образом Ваш вопрос ответа не имеет и не может иметь.

Comment: Вы вывели это утверждение, исходя из формальной теории с набором аксиом `=` `{PHP` - для ламеров`}`, а она, судя по всему, не соответствует формальной теории, привычной автору вопроса :)